# Getting 500 error in MultiversX/Elrond official API

Tags: multiversx

I am wondering why this endpoint sometime returns a 500 error and sometime no ?

https://devnet-api.elrond.com/accounts/erd1rvl2daxdch2xgwd7n6sewjnxg7zu57y0yv82qg6794d4f4qtvqhsxnqfmj/nfts?size=1000&collections=PENGUINS-dd7250,ABG-487603,BACKGROUND-55ab00,ABEAK-6cae95,BEAK-0614cb,ACLOTHES-04a109,CLOTHES-1a78cb,AEYES-c175b6,EYES-a37776,AHAT-a74b10,HAT-cea0c7,ASKIN-f97620,SKIN-ac799c,AWEAPON-965768,WEAPON-e49ce6,EGGS-e93d67

Answer (score 0):

The user account nfts fetches internally esdts from the account trie and sometimes the node / gateway might be overloaded, hence the 500 internal server error if there is a timeout